# Group Records by Sequence Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the below Dataset

```
Date    | status       |
20230101| C            |
20230101| C            |
20230101| R            |
20230101| C            |
20230101| C            |
20230101| R            |
```

I need to perform the grouping in such a way that each status record is compared to it's previous status record, they are the same group if the values are different, else they fall under different group.

the output should be

```
Date    | status       | id
20230101| C            |1
20230101| C            |2
20230101| R            |2
20230101| C            |2
20230101| C            |3
20230101| R            |3
```

```
 Dataset<Row> ds =  dataset
            .withColumn("newVal", when(col("status").equalTo("C"), 1).otherwise(0))
            .withColumn("id", expr("row_number() over (order by Date)"))
            .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY());
```

I don't think this is working , can someone help me ?

always the grouping should start from R

Comment: Pretty sure you need to use `Window` for this to be able to compare one row with the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Group start can be found by comparing current and previous status, and group id assigned by founding group start in range:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("20230101", "C"),
  ("20230101", "C"),
  ("20230101", "R"),
  ("20230101", "C"),
  ("20230101", "C"),
  ("20230101", "R"),
).toDF(
  "Date", "status"
)

val naturalOrderWindow = Window.orderBy(lit(1))
// compare current and previous status
val dateRowNumWindow = Window.orderBy($"Date", $"row_number")
val isGroupStartColumn = coalesce(lag($"status", 1).over(dateRowNumWindow), $"status") === $"status"

val withGroupStartDF = df
  .withColumn("row_number", row_number().over(naturalOrderWindow))
  .withColumn("isGroupStart", isGroupStartColumn)

withGroupStartDF.show(false)

val rowNumberWindow =  Window.orderBy($"row_number").rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)

val result = withGroupStartDF
  .withColumn("id", max(
    when($"isGroupStart", $"row_number").otherwise(0)
  ).over(rowNumberWindow))
  .drop("row_number","isGroupStart")
```

Output:

```
+--------+------+----------+------------+
|Date    |status|row_number|isGroupStart|
+--------+------+----------+------------+
|20230101|C     |1         |true        |
|20230101|C     |2         |true        |
|20230101|R     |3         |false       |
|20230101|C     |4         |false       |
|20230101|C     |5         |true        |
|20230101|R     |6         |false       |
+--------+------+----------+------------+

+--------+------+---+
|Date    |status|id |
+--------+------+---+
|20230101|C     |1  |
|20230101|C     |2  |
|20230101|R     |2  |
|20230101|C     |2  |
|20230101|C     |5  |
|20230101|R     |5  |
+--------+------+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer here is actually an anti-answer. This is not something that should be done in Spark if the data is at scale. Why?

- EXPLAIN reveals on 1st provided solution - `Exchange SinglePartition`, ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [plan_id=xxxx] which means OOM potentially, even with larger partition sizes. Always a bad thing in Spark.
- Repeated calculations in 1st provided solution.
- There is no natural grouping key either to work solely within a partition. 'Date' may have too much data for a partition as well.
- Attempting to solve this with lag, lead functions does not work reliably as lead and lag only work within a partition. As a data wrangler that can be solved, but it gets convoluted, the 1st provided answer is elegant.

So, if data is small, which is counter Spark usage, you can do this in Spark. Otherwise, and actually always, do this in a traditional DB.